# Software Design, a fitting Design Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, php, architecture

Currently we need to interface with a REST API. The only problem we have implementing this is choosing the right approach.

We’ve done this by using Resources – for example a Photo Resource that has certain methods to interface with the REST API. The only problem with this approach is that each time we use a certain Resource we need to inject an Http Client that is being used to perform that task.

So every part of the application that wants to use a certain Resource need to have an extended knowledge of the Http Client. Is there a certain way to solve this problem without using a Singleton – as there is only one instance of the Http Client? Maybe a certain Design Pattern?

For now we make usage of PHP to accomplish this task in combination with Guzzle Http; but this problem is more about Software Architecture.

This is an example of our current implementation:

```
class Photo
{
    /**
      * @var Client $httpClient
      */
    private $httpClient;

    public function __construct($httpClient)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }

    public function getByName($photoName)
    {
        # Use $httpClient
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is actually quite simple, **factories**. The recommended approach would be at least 2 factory methods, one for the `Guzzle` client, the other one for the `Photo` class.

```
class GuzzleFactory
{
    protected $config;

    protected $guzzleClient = null;

    public function __construct(GuzzleConfiguration $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function createGuzzleHttpClientWeakSingleton()
    {
        if ($this->guzzleClient === null) {
            $this->guzzleClient = new \Guzzle\Client($this->config->asArray());
        }

        return $this->guzzleClient;
    }
}

class PhotoFactory
{
    protected $guzzleFactory;

    public function __construct(GuzzleFactory $guzzleFactory)
    {
        $this->guzzleFactory = $guzzleFactory;
    }

    public function createPhotoService()
    {
        return new Photo($this->guzzleFactory->createGuzzleHttpClientWeakSingleton());
    }
}
```

And you're done. Whenever you need an instance of the `Photo` class, create it using the `PhotoFactory` and you will never have more than one instance of http client during a single request (additional configuration is up to you).

Splitting your code into two parts, logic and creational design patterns, is a great way to ensure dependencies are only created as many times as needed.

In case you're wondering why I chose to go the way of a weak singleton instead of the classic `static` path, the reason is unit testing, but if strong singleton with `static` accessor suits your needs more, you can use that one instead and not being forced to pass the `GuzzleFactory`, as it will be globally available.

Comment: Your Guzzle example is completely opaque to me (as are most foobar examples).  However, I upvoted your answer anyway as I, too, believe that some sort of Factory is the correct solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way is to use Dependency Injection. Once set up, your code will look almost the same, just need to add type hint in your Photo constructor:

```
public function __construct(Client $client) {
    $this->client = $client;
}
```

Then in your controller where you want to show the photo, you will have something like this:

```
class Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        // photo here will already have HttpClient injected to it.
        this->photo = DI::get('Photo');
    }

    public function get(id) {
        return $this->photo->get(id);
    }
}
```

DI will pass the client to your Photo constructor. How to configure DI to set up the objects depends on the implementation you use. Here [Zend\DI introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.di.introduction.html) is one example of DI container.

Comment: It's unclear to me how DI  would improve the op's specific situation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I added example controller to show how it'd be useful.